# Measurability with respect to complete filtration

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, measurable-functions, filtrations

I don't know if this is a difficult question, but I have absolutely no intuition about it.

Let us consider a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ supporting a $\mathbb R-$valued stochastic process $(X_t)_{t\in[0,T]}$. Let us denote by $(\mathcal F^X_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ the canonical filtration of $X$, i.e.
$$\mathcal F^X_t = \sigma \left( X_s, s\le t \right).$$
Now, I know that if $Y$ is a $\mathbb R-$valued $\mathcal F^X_t-$measurable random variable,  there exists a Borel function $f$ such that
$$Y = f \big( (X_s)_{s\le t} \big).$$
My question is : is this still true in general if Y is $\overline{\mathcal F}^X_t-$measurable, where $\left(\overline{\mathcal F}^X_t\right)_{t\in [0,T]}$ is the completion of the filtration $(\mathcal F^X_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ ?

Thank you very much for your time !

Comment: Yes. Simply because the completion of a filtration has larger $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: I would guess that you would need $f$ to be Lebesgue measurable rather than just Borel measurable in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your answers; @Kurt G. , wouldn't that imply that if Y is $\overline{\mathcal F}^X_t-$measurable, then it is necessarily $\mathcal F^X_t-$measurable? Is that true?

Comment: No. Exactly not because ${\cal F}_t^X$ is *smaller* than its completion. It can however be true that $Y$ has a modification that is ${\cal F}_t^X$-measurable: namely if $Y=X$ a.s.  If you have trouble to understand what measurability is see what it has to do with continuity of maps w.r.t. a topology. There are a lot of similarities.